# nextjs - calling reset in error.js does not remove small "Error" dialog in bottom-left screen

Tags: next.js

I'm using nextjs just like the docs say, and my error.js is rendering a little clickable widget with "1 Error" in the bottom (it increases every time I get an error, so "2 Error" and so on)

[image]

When I call the `reset()` method, my component re-renders but this thing does not go away. How do I get rid of it at the same time?

Code for error.ts:

```
'use client' // Error components must be Client Components

import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Error({
                                  error,
                                  reset,
                              }: {
    error: Error & { digest?: string }
    reset: () => void
}) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // Log the error to an error reporting service
        console.error(error)
    }, [error])

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>

            <button
                className="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline mt-1"
                onClick={
                    // Attempt to recover by trying to re-render the segment
                    () => reset()
                }
            >
                Try again
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Docs I am reading (they make no mention of this little widget):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling